# Emacs and MySQL on Mac

Tags: mysql, emacs

I tried using the sql-mysql mode but emacs is unable to find the file/directory mysql. However, I can access it from the terminal. How do I point mysql in emacs to /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql ?

Answer (score 4):

`(setq sql-mysql-program "/path/to/your/mysql")`

`(setq sql-user "mysql user")`

`(setq sql-password "password")`

`(setq sql-server "mysql-server")`

`(setq sql-mysql-options "optional command line options")`

supplying some values to these variables through your `.emacs` should help your situation.

Answer (score 2):

You can customize the mysql used by SQL mode in emacs.

```
M-x customize-group [RET] SQL
```

and update the value for mysql.

Answer (score 1):

Your path is probably not being correctly set for emacs sessions.  You can check what paths are being searched for executables with <kbd>C-h v exec-path</kbd>.  A simple way to solve this is to add the needed path entries in your `.emacs` like so:

```
(add-to-list 'exec-path "/path/to/your/mysql")
```